# How can select like multi pattern in a String?

Tags: sql

Ex:
Database Table1:

```
   | ColA |ColB|
   | 1    |A1,A2,A3,A4,A5|
   | 2    |B1,B2|
```

Parameter input: `A4,A1,A2,A5`

I want select row 1, Because `ColB` contain all value of parameter input.

how can do it?

Comment: Store your data in the SQLish way -- a junction table with one row per ColA and ColB value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as @Gordon Linoff says you need to alter your data to a SQLish was, i.e. don't comma separate data but separate them into new rows. This can be achieved by:

*Note I have used MS SQL other versions of SQL will have differing answers but the method should stay the same.*

Sample table

```
CREATE TABLE YourData (ColA int, ColB varchar(max))
INSERT INTO YourData VALUES (1,'A1,A2,A3,A4,A5')
INSERT INTO YourData VALUES (2,'B1,B2')
```

Query (Recursive Common Table Expression)

```
;WITH CTE (ColA, ColB_new, ColB)
AS 
(
SELECT 
ColA
,LEFT(ColB,CHARINDEX(',',ColB+',')-1)
,STUFF(ColB,1,CHARINDEX(',',ColB+','),'')
FROM YourData
UNION ALL
SELECT 
ColA
,LEFT(ColB,CHARINDEX(',',ColB+',')-1)
,STUFF(ColB,1,CHARINDEX(',',ColB+','),'')
FROM CTE
WHERE ColB >''
)
SELECT 
ColA, ColB_new
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ColA
```

So you go from this:

```
   | ColA |ColB|
   | 1    |A1,A2,A3,A4,A5|
   | 2    |B1,B2|
```

To this:

```
ColA    ColB_new
1           A2
1           A3
1           A4
1           A5
1           A1
2           B1
2           B2
```

Then you add a simple `WHERE` clause e.g. `WHERE ColB_new IN('A4','A1','A2','A5')`

If you want to get the information back relating to how it was in the first table (YourData):

```
   | ColA |ColB|
   | 1    |A1,A2,A3,A4,A5|
```

then you can do a `JOIN` on the two tables on ColA